# All days in struts2 datetimepicker are replaced by NaN when we clear the date

Tags: java, struts2, datetimepicker, nan

when we clear the date in Struts2 datetimepicker it is showing a calendar with all days and years are replaced by NaN, months are replaced by undefined.

I am using struts2-dojo-plugin 2.1.6
here is my code

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="application.openDate" id="opendate" displayFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" cssClass="body_1"/>
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: struts2 doesnot provide datetimepicker natively, are you using a plugin? if yes, which one. please provide some code, people can't help with text

Comment: thanks for reply Jaiwo,
yes i am using dojo plugin here is my code

<sx:datetimepicker name="application.openDate" id="opendate" displayFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" cssClass="body_1"/>

Comment: @Hari: why you are using deprecated tags